# How do I target specific element using class

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** this website called startup-India in which I **scrape** the URL and Name of a company but to **scrape** the URL and the Name I have to target them but I don't know which is the right way to target please help.

```
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import scrapy

class WebCrawlerPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item


class ProfileCrawlerPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.urls = list()
        self.companies = list()
        pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item = dict(item)
        url = item.get('item')
        # yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_content)
        # logging.info(url)
        r = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        # url_txt = soup.select('div.container')
        container = soup.find("div", class_="container")
        logging.info(container)
        # # self.write_to_csv()

    def parse_content(self, response):
        logging.info(response.url)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        pass

    def write_to_csv(self):
        pass
```

Code will be appreciated

Comment: We recommend a simpler crawler framework. Here is an example. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/spider_examples

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use BeautifulSoup with Scrapy.

I suggest you take a look at the Scrapy tutorial and use Xpath or CSS selector: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#xpath-a-brief-intro

Comment: I get your point even I'm used to scrapy and very much willingly wanting to use scrapy but the problem is when I'm making a request scrapy does not fire the callback for that reason I'm using beautifulsoup4.